# Navigation system and keep the position of the screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I was wondering how to change my navigation system between pages on a w8 project.

For example I have page 1, panorama with a list of items. If I scroll horizontal until the middle of the screen and I clik on an item I am going page 2. When I click on go back, Frame.GoBack() method is called. It will then reecreate a page, so the user will see the beginning of the panorama.

I was wondering how to keep the screen position? If someone has any links or ideas, they are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

in the constructor of page 1. Normally pages are constructed each time they are navigated to. If you set `NavigationCacheMode`, they will be constructed once[1]. If you later navigate back to it, you won't get a new instance.

[1] If the runtime flushes the cache or you do so by setting the `CacheSize` of the Frame to `0`, the page will be reconstructed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bolgpost that does exactly that. It also handels invalidation of cache

http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/